# Runtime error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f006576)

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am trying to write a function on Xcode that combines two nonincreasing string arrays in nonincreasing order but I run into this error whenever I try to compile. I'm pretty new and have no idea why this happens. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int merge(const string a1[], int size1, const string a2[], int size2, string
          result[], int size){
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1+size2; i++) {
        if (a1[index1] > a2[index2]) {
            result[i] = a1[index1];
            index1++;
        } else {
            result[i] = a2[index2];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    return size1 + size2;
}

int main() {
    string a[4] = {"fgh", "ccc", "abc", "aaa"};
    string b[3] = {"pqr", "def", "bcd"};
    string z[30];
    merge (a, 4, b, 3, z, 30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << z[i] << ", ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to try to debug this, but that error stands for 'general protection fault' and means you accessed invalid memory (probably accessing your arrays out of bounds).

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not executed the program, but it looks your logic is wrong.
If a1[index1] is always smaller than a2[index2], then you will go on increasing index2, even beyond size2. I guess that is what happening with your case when you are trying to compare "abc" and "bcd", here index2 would get incremented to 3, and there is no a2[3].
Please debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong in the merge function.! And also `merge` is a function which is returning `integer data` according to the function definition. But in the main function, it looks like a function which is returning `void`.!
The runtime error you are getting because when the a2[index2] is trying to access a2[4] which is not valid !
So, replace the code with the below snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int merge(const string a1[], int size1, const string a2[], int size2, string
    result[], int size){
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1+size2; i++) {
        if (a1[index1] > a2[index2]) {
            result[i] = a1[index1];
            index1++;
        }
        else {
            result[i] = a2[index2];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    return size1 + size2;
}

int main() {
    int res;
    string a[4] = { "fgh", "ccc", "abc", "aaa" };
    string b[4] = { "pqr", "def", "bcd" };
    string z[30];
    res = merge(a, 4, b, 3, z, 30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << z[i] << ", ";
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it will work fine now !

Comment: @Arthur: Please upvote and accept the answer if it is working for you!!